# Vuejs: Is it possible to put double braces {{}} in a href tag?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to put double braces `{{ }}` in a href tag?

```
<a href="{{link}}">Mylink</a>


var myObject = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {link: 'http://google.com'}
})
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try <a :href="link">MyLink</a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, is not possible. The correct way is to use `v-bind`:

```
<a v-bind:href="link">Mylink</a>
```

Or in shorthand:

```
<a :href="link">Mylink</a>
```